# Finding $f'(x)$ when $f(x)=\int^1_0 e^{xy+y^2}dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> If $f(x) = \int^1_0 e^{xy+y^2}dy$, find $f'(0)$.

I understand that this is function defined by an integral, and $e^{y^{2}}$ does not integrate into an elementary function. So, I will need to take $f'(x)$ which yields:

$$\int^1_0 ye^{xy+y^2}dy$$

I am trying to integrate this, but I am failing. I take it I should use integration by parts, but I can't because I still have $e^{y^2}$ term. Any help?

Comment: You want to calculate $f^{\prime}(0)$, so plug $x = 0$ and it will be an easy integral.

Comment: Derive under the integration sign, this is smooth and it will be allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asked to calculate $f^{\prime}(0)$. You don't have to calculate $f^{\prime}(x)$ first.

\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(0) = \int_0^1 y e^{y^2}dy
\end{align}

Let $u = y^2$, $du = 2ydy$:

\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(0) &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 e^u du = \left. \frac{1}{2}e^u \right|_0^1 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(e - 1)
\end{align}

As for the general case of $f^\prime(x)$, the integral cannot be solved using elementary functions only. One will have to use the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Answer (score 3):

You are given

$$f(x) =\int_0^1 \exp(xy+y^2)dy $$

Differentiating gives

$$f'(x) =\int_0^1 y\cdot \exp(xy+y^2)dy $$

Since we need $f'(0)$ we might as well plug in $x=0$. This gives

$$f'(0) =\int_0^1 y\cdot \exp (y^2)\cdot dy $$

But this integral is quite striaghtforward,

$$f'(0) =\int_0^1 y\cdot \exp (y^2)\cdot dy =\left. \frac 1 2 e^{y^2} \right|_0^1 = \frac 1 2 (e-1) $$

---

By the OP's request:

$$f'(x) =\int_0^1 y\cdot \exp(xy+y^2)dy $$

We complete the square

$$f'(x) = \exp \left( { - \frac{{{x^2}}}{4}} \right)\int_0^1 {y\exp \left[ {{{\left( {y + \frac{x}{2}} \right)}^2}} \right]dy} $$

We change variables

$$\eqalign{
  & y + \frac{x}{2} = u  \cr 
  & dy = du \cr} $$

$$\eqalign{
  & f'(x) = \exp \left( { - \frac{{{x^2}}}{4}} \right)\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{1 + \frac{x}{2}} {\left( {u - \frac{x}{2}} \right)} \exp \left( {{u^2}} \right)du  \cr 
  & f'(x) = \exp \left( { - \frac{{{x^2}}}{4}} \right)\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{1 + \frac{x}{2}} u \exp \left( {{u^2}} \right)du - \frac{x}{2}\exp \left( { - \frac{{{x^2}}}{4}} \right)\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{1 + \frac{x}{2}} {\exp \left( {{u^2}} \right)du}  \cr} $$

Let's focus on the first integral:

$${I_1} = \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{1 + \frac{x}{2}} u \exp \left( {{u^2}} \right)du = \left. {\frac{1}{2}\exp {u^2}} \right|_{x/2}^{1 + x/2} = \frac{1}{2}\exp \frac{{{x^2}}}{4}\left[ {\exp \left( {x + 1} \right) - 1} \right]$$

So we have

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\exp \left( {x + 1} \right) - 1} \right] - \frac{x}{2}\exp \left( { - \frac{{{x^2}}}{4}} \right)\int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{1 + \frac{x}{2}} {\exp \left( {{u^2}} \right)du} $$

The other integral evaluates in terms of the error function

$$\operatorname{erf} (x) = \frac{2}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_0^x {{e^{ - {t^2}}}} dt.$$

with a change or variables $u=-v$,

$$\int_{ - \left( {1 + \frac{x}{2}} \right)}^{ - \frac{x}{2}} {\exp \left( { - {v^2}} \right)dv}  = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}\left\{ {\operatorname{erf} \left( { - \frac{x}{2}} \right) - \operatorname{erf} \left( { - 1 - \frac{x}{2}} \right)} \right\}$$

So the function is

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\exp \left( {x + 1} \right) - 1} \right] - \frac{x}{2}\exp \left( { - \frac{{{x^2}}}{4}} \right)\frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}\left\{ {\operatorname{erf} \left( { - \frac{x}{2}} \right) - \operatorname{erf} \left( { - 1 - \frac{x}{2}} \right)} \right\}$$

For large values of $x$, you can neglect the last result ([since the value will be smaller and smaller](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x/2%20exp%28-x%5E2/4%29%2a%28erf%28-x/2%29-erf%28-1-x/2%29%29%20in%20%282,7%29)), and you can estimate $f'$ with

$$f'(x) \approx \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\exp \left( {x + 1} \right) - 1} \right]$$

Cheers.

Comment: If you put $x = 0$ in immediately after differentiating, you'll be able to skip a few steps... (edit: looks like you've done this now)

Comment: @benmachine I was thinking about finding the general $f'$ but then I changed my mind and that's why that mid step was kind of stranded there.

Comment: @Peter, how would one go about finding the general f'? Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Donnie There is no elementary closed form of $f'$, but you can get a good approximation for large values of $x$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Thank you very much. This is quite interesting.

Comment: @Donnie Any time!

Answer (score 0):

You have got f'(x), so let x be 0, and integrate by parts. Then you get the answer (e-1)/2.

Comment: Pan Yan, if you look at the other two anwers, you can see you are simply repeating in a summarized way what has been already been explained. It isn't useful to repeat what other questions say, but rather to add **extra** remarks, ideas or information. This question, as it is, is not useful for the OP.